# Contempo theme - How can I get rid of the small white rectangles in post' cover pictures?

Tags: html, blogger, blogspot

we have the following blog:

https://atlantidivaganti.blogspot.it/

and we would like to know how to get rid of the white rectangles in the lower left corner of the post cover pictures that appear in the main page of the blog.

The only solution we've found was to set the background color as "transparent" following: Theme -> Customize/Personalize -> Advanced -> Background Color ("Colore sfondo" in Italian). But if we do so, the "Follow by Email" ("Iscriviti" in Italian) gadget appears transparent as well, and it is not easy to see.

I have prepared some slides to explain better the issue:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
Thanks again in advance for your support and ciao,

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please try to improve the question by including content directly in your question. An uploaded screenshot would be better then an external link. Also some code would be essential.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following CSS via Theme  Customise  Advanced  Add CSS

```
.snippet-thumbnail .post-header {
    background: transparent;
}
```

Comment: Hello Prayag, it worked perfectly!
Thanks a lot for your precious help!